# saveas of object failed when trying to save an .xlsx file

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create an application which is trying to execute the below logic

1. I have a work sheet which has two columns, product code and product category
2. For each product category there should be one excel file. The products of those category all would get copied to a work sheet in the newly created excel file.

Looping through each row in the work sheet which contains the product code and category. wkScrap holds the reference
to the temporary/scrap work sheet.

```
wkScrap.Activate 
lProdRow = Cells(rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 

'loop through each row and get the product id and the category 
'ignore first row, it is the header
Dim catWorkBook As Workbook
oProductCat = "0" 'the initial value set as 0, which would NEVER be a category
With wkScrap
    For i = 2 To lProdRow
        cProductCode = .Cells(i, 1).Value
        cProductCat = .Cells(i, 2).Value

        'will need to open a category specific .xls file
        If (StrComp(cProductCat, oProductCat) <> 0) Then
            'save the existing workbook
            FileIO.CloseExcelFile oProductCat, catWorkBook

            Set catWorkBook = Nothing 'clear all traces of the old worksheet
            Set catWorkBook = CreateBlankWorkBook()
            MsgBox (cProductCat + " " + catWorkBook.Name)
            oProductCat = cProductCat
        End If


        'catWorkBook.Save 'we keep on saving any ways.
    Next
End With
```

The issue I am facing is when I am trying to save the catWorkBook, I am getting a

> method saveas of object _workbook failed

error. Below is the method which I use to save the excel file.

```
Sub CloseExcelFile(catCode As String, newWkBook As Workbook)

    If newWkBook Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    newWkBook.Activate 'activate or this work sheet would not be able to save it is
    MsgBox ("Activated the workbook")
    Dim slash As String
    slash = "\"
    Dim ext As String
    ext = ".xlsx"
    Dim qualifiedFileName As String
    Dim onlyFileName As String
    onlyFileName = fileName + ext
    qualifiedFileName = salesReportPath + slash + onlyFileName

    'Save the file
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    newWkBook.SaveAs fileName:=qualifiedFileName
    newWkBook.Close
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Why I am getting this error? Is it because I am looping through a work sheet, and at the same time trying to activate and save another work sheet?

PS: I am yet to write the logic to actually move the products of a specific category to the newly created excel sheet.

Comment: What does qualifiedFileName returns , Is it a valid path ?

Comment: Yes. It is to return the full qualified path of the workbook which is actually trying to do this job (i.e ThisWorkbook).

Comment: Is it a path on network , could you paste the path here ?

Comment: Where is the var `fileName` set?  Can you manually save as `qualifiedFileName`?  Have you tried with `DisplayAlerts ` on?  Possible that this is hiding an error you need to be aware of.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved. It was a hectic day, and I had made two mistakes in the subroutine CloseExcelFile

Error #1

```
onlyFileName = fileName + ext
```

FileName was not even defined in the program. The file name had to be a combination of category (catCode) and the .xlsx extension.

Error #2

```
qualifiedFileName = salesReportPath + slash + onlyFileName
```

I assumed that the salesReportPath would always be a valid path. But that was not the case. It was only getting set, if I followed a specific pattern of running the Macro. I corrected that as well.

@Imran Malek, @destination-data 17: Your questions made me recheck the code, and that helped me find the answer as well. Thanks!!!